# Non Functional Requirement of a Laptop?

Tags: non-functional, requirements-engineering

If we want to find of Non functional Requirements of a system, What would be it in generally?

In example. I want to know the non-functional requirements of a Laptop?

Comment: For instance, weight, physical dimensions, power consumption, etc?

Answer (score 3):

Some points would include,

Battery back time.
Screen resolution.
Its weight.
Its dimensions.
What accessories come along with it.
...
And you can keep on going with your list of expectations.